# Telegram Bot SendDocument pdf

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I am having a real headache with the way of sending a pdf file to a Telegram Bot.
Apparently I am following the documentation but never get it sent.
I am using the url: https://api.telegram.org/botBOTID/sendDocument?chat_id=CHATID&document=/home/lix/Downloads/2.pdf

It is a pdf file storaged locally, but I think it is just the way I am presenting it.
The error getting is:
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: URL host is empty"}
Does anybody knows how to send a pdf local file?
Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should send a *POST* request, with the PDF as a payload, using the [Python Requests library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/), your code should look something like this:

```py
import requests

# Url with bot token + user id
url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<MY-BOT-TOKEN>/sendDocument?chat_id=<MY_CHAT_ID>"

# Create payload with PDF file
payload = {}
files = [
    ('document', open('/home/lix/Downloads/2.pdf','rb'))
]
headers= {}

# Request
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, files = files)

# Log reponse as UTF-8
print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```